# Python BigQuery: Inserting strings whose content is numeric fails

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create some code that inserts data into Google Big Query but cannot be sure what the content of String fields is exactly. Apparently Big Query has problems with strings like "1.1" or "1"

Consider a Big Query table of the following minimal schema (only one string field called 
"stringer":

```
[
  {
    "description": "string_debug",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "stringer",
    "type": "STRING"
  }
]
```

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_id = 'bqsoba'
table_id = 'stringer'

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
job_config.autodetect = False

job = client.load_table_from_json([{'stringer':'1'}], table_ref, job_config=job_config)

job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.

print("Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.".format(job.output_rows, dataset_id, table_id))
```

Results in an exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadRequest                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-3d68dddf9573> in <module>
     13 job = client.load_table_from_json(parsed[11:20], table_ref, job_config=job_config)
     14 
---> 15 job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
     16 
     17 print("Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.".format(job.output_rows, dataset_id, table_id))

~/apps/conda2019/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py in result(self, timeout, retry)
    777             self._begin(retry=retry)
    778         # TODO: modify PollingFuture so it can pass a retry argument to done().
--> 779         return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout)
    780 
    781     def cancelled(self):

~/apps/conda2019/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py in result(self, timeout)
    125             # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
    126             # Pylint doesn't recognize that this is valid in this case.
--> 127             raise self._exception
    128 
    129         return self._result

BadRequest: 400 Provided Schema does not match Table bi-project-231313:bqsoba.sa_hardware_collector. Field sysconfig.call_home_token has changed type from STRING to INTEGER
```

Is it possible to ask the Big Query "insert" to treat '1' as a string value?

Comment: Have you tried manually specifying a schema: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#specify-schema-manual-python

Comment: Naturally so, That's how I defined the Schema in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your schema manually:

```
schema =   [{
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "stringer",
    "type": "STRING"
  }]
```

And then use it before the job execution:

```
job_config.schema = schema
```

I hope it helps you